# Can I have a docking station to support 2 addtional monitors for my laptop?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a HP 17-p161dx 17.3″ Notebook - A10 -7300 1.9 GHz - 6 GB RAM - 1 TB HDD lap top and I currently use the laptop and one additional monitor, how do I add a 3rd monitor via a docking station or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your third monitor has an HDMI port, one of the simplest ways to add it may be to buy an adapter, like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BPEV1XK), which utilizes a USB 3.0 port. (Other adapters that output to VGA, DVI, and other ports are also available.)

Your laptop probably doesn't have a dock specifically made for it (I didn't check), but there are more "generic" docks that attach via USB out there, though they may not address your monitor situation.

Comment: Thank you! I was told that I had to check my graphics card to be sure my laptop can handle two additional monitors. I'm just not sure how any of it works to be honest.

Comment: There are also USB3 docks that allow connecting 2 or more additional monitors. These docks have their own GPU inside them, making the internal laptop GPU of less importance.

Comment: Do you have a particular brand or recommend something?